# Why is my DP solution for maximum length of longest chain getting TLE?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

For this question at https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-length-of-pair-chain, I am getting TLE for my DP solution as shown below. According to my intuition, it should pass since it is O(n*m) where n = length of pairs array and m = range of numbers in pairs array (2000 max). Can anyone help?

I understand the solution in the editorial but just can't wrap my head around why this won't work.

```
def findLongestChain(self, pairs: List[List[int]]) -> int:
    @lru_cache
    def rec(i, j):
        if i == n:
            return 0
        ans = 0
        if pairs[i][0] > j:
            ans = rec(i+1, pairs[i][1]) + 1
        ans = max(ans, rec(i+1, j))
        return ans
        
    
    n = len(pairs)
    pairs.sort()
    return rec(0, -1001))
```